# If $X^2$ follows the exponential distribution, how to prove that $X$ obeys what kind of distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

If $X^2$ follows the exponential distribution, how to prove that $X$ obeys what kind of distribution?
As we all know, if $X$ follows the Rayleigh, then $X^2$ follows the exponential distribution. Otherwise, if $X^2$ follows the exponential distribution, will $X$ only obey Rayleigh distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $Y=\sqrt{X}, X \sim Exp(\lambda)$, then derive CDF of $Y$:
$$
P(Y<y) = P(\sqrt{X}<y) = P(X<y^2) = P(0<X<y^2)
$$
Can you handle from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! Ah, i really made a fool of myself.

Answer (score 0):

If $X^2$ follows an exponential distribution (a chi-squared distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom and a suitable scale factor), then you can conclude that $|X|$ follows the Rayleigh distribution (i.e. the [chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) with $2$ degrees of freedom and a suitable scale factor).  You can use cumulative distribution functions to prove this.

You need to believe $X$ is non-negative to conclude this also is the distribution for $X$; if not then there are many possibilities.

Comment: OK, thank you ~

Comment: why do I need to 'believe' $X$ is nonnegative? Exponential distribution is defined this way

Comment: Indeed the exponential distribution is defined to be on the non-negative reals, and $X^2$ is clearly non-negative.  But $X$ has not been defined that way and so could be negative, or a simple or complicated mixture of positive and negative